# Proving there exists a prime $q$ such that for every integer $n$, the number $n^p-p$ is not divisible by $q$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The problem I found was from the 2003 IMO Problem 6.

Let p be a prime number. Prove that there exists a prime q such that for every integer n, the number $n^p-p$ is not divisible by q.

I studied one version of the solution which started with the expanded form of the equation, 
$${\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}}$$
Then, it is quite obvious that we would find atleast one prime divisor of ${\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}}$ which is not congruent to $1$ $mod$ $p^2$. Denoting this prime divisor as $q$. And in the  solution it stated that this $q$ is what we wanted.

I don't understand why this is *the q* we  sought for in the first place. I also don't understand how this $q$ is related to the $q$ we wanted in forming the proof.

Also, from the method of reasoning in the solution, it deduced by stating Fermat's Little Theorem that $n^{q-1}=1$mod$q$. I don't understand how $n$ is coprime to $q$, because this version of FLT is true only for $(q,n)=1$
[image]

So, please help me clear my doubts and also if it wouldn't be too much of a trouble, please tell​ your versions of the solution. FYI, I have also tried reading the discussions on Art of problem solving site, that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $q \mid n$, then $q\mid n^p-p$ implies that $q\mid p$, but it is obvious that $\gcd(p,q)=1$.  For the other question, it's better that you point out what you don't understand.

---

> **Claim:**  If $q$ is a prime natural number such that $n^p-p$ is not divisible by $q$ for every integer $n$, then $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

*Proof:* First, it is obvious that $q\neq p$.   If $q\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$, then $p\nmid q-1$, and therefore any residue modulo $q$ has a $p$-th root modulo $q$.  To show this, we note that $px+(q-1)y=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus, for any $a\not\equiv0\pmod{p}$, we have
$$\left(a^x\right)^p=a^{px}\equiv a^{px}(1)^{y}\equiv a^{px}\left(a^{q-1}\right)^y=a^{px+(q-1)y}=a^1=a\pmod{q}\,.$$
In particular, the congruence $n^p\equiv p\pmod{q}$ has a solution modulo $q$.  This is a contradiction, so $q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ has to be satisfied.

Comment: But my question was is it obvious that $(q,n)=1$?

Comment: You don't understand what I said.  If $q\nmid n$, then the official solution handles it.  The official solution ignores the case $q\mid n$ because, as I stated in my answer, this is the trivial case.

Comment: Ok. So, the first question was, are we choosing $n$ to be $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ ?

Comment: No, $n$ is arbitrary.  As for your last question, my solution to this problem is almost exactly the official solution.  I was there in Japan.

Comment: So why the need for the equation $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$

Comment: To find $q$.  Read the definition of $q$ again.

Comment: So, we are trying to find the $q$ which posses the property asked by the question?

Comment: Yes.  (This sentence is to fill in the character limit.)

Comment: So, we are using the $q$ which is one of the prime divisor of the equation $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ to assume the correctness of the statement $n^p-p=$$mod$$q$ so as to find a contradiction that it is not so?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ has a prime divisor $q\not\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$.  And any such prime divisor $q$ satisfies the property that $n^p-p$ is not divisible by $q$ for every integer $n$.

Comment: That's what I was saying. Thanks for clarifying explicitly. I'll keep in touch if I have problems.

Comment: How did we know that $q$ is found as one of the prime divisors contained inside $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ in the first place? And how do we look for them(the appropriate construct)?

Comment: Pulling out $q$ from $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$ to satisfy the property gives me rabbit out of the hat feeling.

Comment: Well, read Comment 1 in the official solution.  It gives an explanation of this "pulling a rabbit out of a hat" trick.

Comment: Yes. But how does one know $q$ has to be of the form $pk+1$? That would mean $k$ should be even and not an odd number greater than 1.

Comment: ? (This sentence is to fill the min character)

Comment: I have other businesses to attend to and can't immediately reply to your question.  Your question has been clarified in the answer.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that $q$ which is a prime can be written as $pk+1$ where $k$ is positive? This could cut to the chase without extrapolating the reason. Euclid's representation of prime numbers

Comment: When I first read your name, I read Batmanovski hahah.

Comment: Thank you Batominovski! I finally understand your solution after 7 years. I couldn't find the time to actually read number theory, but this week I took the time to gather the courage to get to it. I got it! Thanks again. This has impeded my study of NT for the last decade. Now I can move on to other problems :)